# Compare two datatables using two columns in each and return a list of non-matching records

Tags: c#, linq

I've got the syntax for comparing a two datatables using a single column figured out, but I'm stuck how to compare two datatables using two columns.

```
IEnumerable<string> assocInAD = dtAssoc.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row["parent_guid"] + " " + (string)row["child_guid"]);
IEnumerable<string> assocInDB = dtAssocData.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row["parent_guid"] + " " + (string)row["child_guid"]);
IEnumerable<string> assocNotinAD = assocInAD.Except(assocInDB);
```

I tried this, but I'm getting everything instead of just the records that are non-matching.

For clarity's sake, I'm writing a program that updates an Oracle database with Active Directory Users, Groups and the associations between all of them (including associations between groups).  I've got the initial population down and any additions or deletions, but what I'm fighting is managing when a User or Group is removed from a Group.  I've populated two datatables with the relevant data (two column datatables with parent GUID and child GUID) from my Oracle DB and Active Directory and now I need to find the discrepancies between the two.  I've got comparing a single value down pat, but I'm stuck on comparing two values.

Comment: Except should get you the unmatching data. But when doing assocInAD.Except(assocInDB);, you will get all the items in AD which are not in DB.In case you want to find which are not in AD, you may try reversing this -IEnumerable<string> assocNotinAD = assocInDB.Except(assocInAD);

Comment: I was able to hack things together by concatenating the two guids together with a separator and then using @Vishnu's tip.   I doubt that it's an optimal solution, but it does do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think `GroupJoin` will do the trick:

```
var assocInAD = 
    dtAssoc
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        ParentGuid = (string)row["parent_guid"],
        ChildGuid = (string)row["child_guid"]
    });

var assocInDB = 
    dtAssocData
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        ParentGuid = (string)row["parent_guid"],
        ChildGuid = (string)row["child_guid"]
    });

var missingInDB =
    assocInAD
    .GroupJoin(
        assocInDB,
        left => (left.ParentGuid, left.ChildGuid),
        right => (right.ParentGuid, right.ChildGuid),
        (left, right) => (left, right))
    .Where(x => !x.right.Any())
    .Select(x => x.left);

var missingInAD =
    assocInDB
    .GroupJoin(
        assocInAD,
        left => (left.ParentGuid, left.ChildGuid),
        right => (right.ParentGuid, right.ChildGuid),
        (left, right) => (left, right))
    .Where(x => !x.right.Any())
    .Select(x => x.left);
```

Comment: This code won't compile.  Throwing errors all through the two GroupJoin statements.